# Is there a way to program for gameboy?

Tags: language-agnostic

Is there a way to program for gameboy?

Comment: Excellent question - though you would need a way to create the chip and the plastic cartredge (sp?)

Comment: I believe you can get those online. I saw it once and now can't find the link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Boy_Advance_flash_cartridge
Btw this is how you port your games to GBA

Answer (score 2):

http://www.loirak.com/gameboy/gbprog.php

From link:

> Have you ever dreamed of becomming a
>   game programmer? Today is your lucky
>   day, ...

Answer (score 2):

Glad to see someone else interested in this. This http://www.coranac.com/tonc/text/ is the guide I used it's the most comprehensive in terms of programming IMHO. However I used this site http://www.gbajunkie.co.uk/  Docs&Tutorials --> Setting Up to set up the development environment.

Development will be in C or Cpp I tend to use C because why not.

During development you'll want to use an emulator to test your programs as its faster a good one is visualboy advance.

However at some point you will want to run your games on "Real Iron" you can do this by use Flash Carts however they tend to be rarer than rocking horse poo. I use a MiniSd superCard (A cartdrige that reads roms from a mini SD) that way you can have all you games as well as your programs.

Good luck